# Is .NET 2.0 required to run .NET 3.5

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework

I'm trying to deploy .NET to some Windows XP machines using Group Policies and I was wondering wether I need to deploy older version of .NET to make newer version work. I want to install up to .NET 3.5.

And if I need to install previous versions of .NET to make 3.5 work, how can I make it so that .NET 2.x installs first using Group Policies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, .NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 are cumulative.

Other versions have varying forward-compatiblity:

- .NET 1.1 apps will automatically run with only .NET 2.0+ installed.  There may be some small compatibility glitches.  That leads to:
- .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 apps can run with only 4.0 installed *only if they have been set to do so* (to avoid compatibility issues)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll deploy 4.0 to one of our systems and see if it works! :-)

Comment: .NET 4.0-only will probably have compatibility issues with apps written for previous versions unless you or the programmer has said "this app can run on 4.0 also".